# shinydashboardPlus: Opening a closed boxPlus

Tags: r, shinydashboard

How can I open (using code) a closed boxPlus?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinydashboardPlus/vignettes/improved-boxes.html

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for answer for the same question and I've figured out how to do this with shinyjs.

```
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    boxPlus(
      id = "openable-box-plus",
      title = "Openable boxPlus",
      closable = TRUE
    ),
    actionButton(
      inputId = "open-box-plus",
      label = "Open boxPlus"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(
    input$`open-box-plus`,
    runjs('
      document
        .querySelector("#openable-box-plus")
        .parentElement
        .style.display = "block";
    ')
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When you check HTML of the boxPlus before and after closing it, you can see that style `display: none;` is added to the `<div>` with `class="box"`.

[image]

To select specific `boxPlus` I added `id = "openable-box-plus"`. Since `id` went to the child `div` of `div` with `display` style, you have to select parent element, and change `display` to `"block"`:

```
document
  .querySelector("#openable-box-plus")
  .parentElement
  .style.display = "block";
```